# Safari rendering bugs with React and Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, material-ui

I am running into a bug in Safari where some forms are being rendered on initial load of my react app, but after the first action is taken by a user, they get pushed to the top. It seems like some ghost elements are being rendered but do not appear in the inspector. This does not happen in any other modern browser, only Safari.

[Example of what looks like elements being duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7RRu.png)

The inputs are all Material-UI TextField components, and as you can see the background stays in place, but the actual inputs are moved up and text is duplicated.

[Example of inputs being pushed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrDgf.png)

Here we have a header that renders exactly where it should, yet the inputs and the button get pushed up while the select field remains in place.

We have code in place to deal with different screen sizes, but even with disabling all of this as well as disabling any flexbox containers or anything else that make things move responsively, we still see this bug. Has anyone experienced anything like this and found a solution? Thanks

Comment: May you reproduce this bug in codesandbox.io ? It is not so easy to help you without seeing some code.

Comment: I'm having similar issues. Did you ever find the cause?